# Cannot access outlook.office365.com

Tags: thunderbird, email, ms-exchange

I must say I'm a new Ubuntu user. I'm using 14.04 LTS version. I always keep my Ubuntu updated. I've an office365 account and I already configured it in Thunderbird. It was working fine, so far. Today I've installed a new update and outlook.office365.com has become inaccessible. Neither Thunderbird not browsers (Chrome, Firefox) can access this host. I get timeout in both cases. If I try to look up it I get this:

```
$ nslookup outlook.office365.com
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

It's also timeout. So I don't think this problem is an application specific problem because I get the same error in all cases. My precise version is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux lomniczi-pc 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Firewall is inactive (ufw).
I'm sure outlook.office365.com can be resolved and replies since I've checked it on Windows; I can use my account from browser and I can use Outlook application to access my emails connecting to this host. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked your Internet connection?

Comment: Yes, of course, I have. I was able to access other hosts. Meantime I found the solution: I set the Google nameserver in the /etc/resolv.conf: 8.8.8.8

Comment: same thing over here. I can ping it, but cannot access it via firefox even with the IP.

Comment: Please consider posting your comment as an answer, since it appears others are having the same difficulty.

Comment: I have this problem in specific networks. Gmail works well but office365 accounts fails. Some possibilities are restrictions of network or change of IP used for access (because OWA use GeoDNS).

Answer (score 0):

From Terminal

```
cd /etc
ls
```

Look for resolv.conf, if it exists then,

```
sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/backup.resolv.conf
```

This copies the file to a new file name in case you need it back.

Exit Terminal, go to Firefox and try your URL.  It should work fine.